# How to capture image hold event in android webview?

Tags: android

Many mobile web browsers have some default functionality on image hold. For example, user is shown an option to save or copy or move to link option, if he holds a image on a browser.

Can the same functionality be replicated in android app using a webview? Is there some default settings available or do I need to code for such functionality?

Comment: I think it may possible with context menu.

Comment: @YugandharBabu, But how will I capture the event that user is holding an image in webview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not able to find a perfect solution yet, but this might do the trick.

In `onCreate()`:

```
registerForContextMenu(mWebView);
```

And override the `onCreateContextMenu()` method:

```
@Override  
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  

    HitTestResult result = ((WebView) v).getHitTestResult();

    MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener handler = new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            // do the menu action
            return true;
        }
    };

    if (result.getType() == HitTestResult.IMAGE_TYPE ||
            result.getType() == HitTestResult.SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE) {
        // Menu options for an image.
        //set the header title to the image url
        menu.setHeaderTitle(result.getExtra());
        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Save Image").setOnMenuItemClickListener(handler);
        menu.add(0, 2, 0, "View Image").setOnMenuItemClickListener(handler);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi, Kamal, The above answer helped me a lot, now I am getting options like save image and view image when I hold down on an image in webView. so now how can I download the image when the user clicks save image button. please help me in this regard. Thanks in advance.